# Rendering a local HTML file with a local image in WebView

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I am trying to render a local html file with a local image in a WebView where the WebView is in a Dialog Box and not an Activity. The image is not being rendered, but the remainder of the info is displayed just fine.

There are countless solutions to this problem suggested in Stack Overflow, many with green check marks. None that I have tried have worked.

What I am doing is placing the html file and the image in res/raw
The html file has a line referencing the image; I have tried different options all which have been stated somewhere in stack overflow as working, for example:

```
<img src="file:///android_res/raw/main_screen_crop.png" alt="Main Screen" width="525" height="290">
```

and

```
<img src="main_screen_crop.png" alt="Main Screen" width="525" height="290">
```

The text part of the html renders fine, but for the image I get just the 'alt' text inside an empty box with a thumbnail picture icon.

So the questions I have are:

- Is accessing an image when the html of a WebView is rendered inside a Dialog Box different than an Activity making the suggested solutions invalid?
- Some answers said "place the image in the assets directory and use the file:///..." to reference the image AND they indicated that this was required which contradicts other
  solutions. Is the use of the assets directory required?
- Android has a 2018 tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGZYtDZhOEQ stating that many of the StackOverflow answers on how to handle WebView are just plain wrong but admit it is partly their fault due to out of date documentation ...

Here is my render code which works just fine for everything else!

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") // Okay on dialog
    final View helpContent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.help_screen, null);

    // Get the Alert Dialog Builder
    android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    TextView customTitle = new TextView(context);
    // Customise Title here
    customTitle.setText(title);
    customTitle.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorToolbarBackground));
    customTitle.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    customTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    customTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    customTitle.setTextSize(20);

    builder.setCustomTitle(customTitle)
    WebView help = helpContent.findViewById(R.id.helpView);
    help.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    String helpText = readRawTextFile(htmlpage); // reads the html file
    help.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);  // This did not help ...
    help.loadData(helpText, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
    builder.setView(helpContent); // put view in Dialog box
```

Any help, clarification, etc. as to what is correct will be greatly appreciated!
Should add that the html file, when clicked on in Windows, renders fine in a browser.

Comment: if you modify it a bit,it will work

Comment: "What I am doing is placing the html file and the image in res/raw" -- I recommend `assets/`. "Is the use of the assets directory required?" -- I have never tried that `android_res` thing; almost everything I see uses `assets/`. "Is accessing an image when the html of a WebView is rendered inside a Dialog Box different than an Activity making the suggested solutions invalid?" -- it shouldn't be.

Comment: yes @CommonsWare answer will work.try and let us know.

Comment: @CommonsWare bummer! I just tried that. Created an assets directory, put the image in it, and set <img src="file:///android_assets/main_screen_crop.png" alt="Main Screen" width="525" height="290"> and I got the same result.

Comment: It's `android_asset` (singular), not `android_assets` (plural). The *directory* is `assets/` (plural), but the fake entry in the URL is singular. And, no, I don't know why they did it that way... :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare good to know but it still did not work; same result.Do I have to have the html file in the assets directory as well? If so that will take a bit of effort to fix...

Comment: I assumed that it was there already, given your earlier statement ("What I am doing is placing the html file and the image in res/raw"). Move both to `assets/`, and use `loadUrl()`, not `loadData()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare That DID work ... with one extra step. I had to delete the image file in the 'raw' directory. Write up you answer so I can check it. Should also add what DIDN'T work (contrary to other posted answers)

Comment: @CommonsWare if you know how to scale JUST the image to the width (leaving everything else as if the image were not there) that would be most appreciated! Most apps seem to want to use the entire webview for their image but in my case its only part of the webview ... its a help screen actually...

Comment: "Write up you answer so I can check it" -- I recommend that you answer your own question, demonstrating what worked for  you. "if you know how to scale JUST the image to the width" -- I would imagine that there's some CSS that you could apply for that, but I don't recall the details off the top of my head, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following CommonWare's suggestion, I will answer this question and state what worked for me. I was also able to scale the image independently of the text.

I was unable to get the image to render when my image and html file were in the res/raw directory. I tried many combinations and failed. I will not state that it is impossible.

What DID work was creating a directory named assets at the same level as the src directory and placing BOTH my image file and html file in that directory. As CommonWare pointed out, the URL for the files is

```
"file:///android_asset/main_screen_crop.png"
```

even though the directory name is 'assets'.

The code simplifies to

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") // Okay on dialog
    final View helpContent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.help_screen, null);

    // Get the Alert Dialog Builder
    android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    TextView customTitle = new TextView(context);
    // Customise Title here
    customTitle.setText(title);
    customTitle.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorToolbarBackground));
    customTitle.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    customTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    customTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    customTitle.setTextSize(20);

    builder.setCustomTitle(customTitle);

    WebView help = helpContent.findViewById(R.id.helpView);
    help.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    
    help.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    help.loadUrl(htmlpage);

    builder.setView(helpContent);
```

where 'htmlpage' is, for example,

```
"file:///android_asset/layout_help.html"
```

The html file itself (with independent scaling of text and image) becomes:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .gfg {
        width:auto;
        text-align:center;
        padding:2px;
    }
    img {
        max-width:100%;
                height:auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Running the Application</h3>
After pressing start you will see a screen as follows:
<div class="gfg">
    <p id="my-image">
        <img src="file:///android_asset/main_screen_crop.png" alt="Main Screen"/>
    </p>
</div>
</html>
```

Hope this saves someone the 7 hrs it took me to get it to work.

Comment: Accept it as the correct answer please if it fixed your problem

Comment: @Steven did so. Still using it and it does the job.I have not tried further variants on my original approaches.