# How to handle input type file in WebChromeClient using Kotlin in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-webview, webchromeclient

Can any please help me to implement WebChromeClient to handle input type file in webview using Kotlin. I have searched everywhere and I am unable to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a file in your drawable or resources folder which you are trying to render on webview.

Use the default convertor in Android Studio, to convert the code into Kotlin.

Try to take a hint from here.

[Rendering a local HTML file with a local image in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56186056/rendering-a-local-html-file-with-a-local-image-in-webview)